# Can Aereni Focus and Skill Focus be stacked?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, skills

Aereni Focus says that it counts as Skill Focus for meeting requirements/prerequisites. So, for instance, I could take Aereni Focus (Listen) and I would qualify for the Keen-Eared Scout feat through that. However, it doesn't say anything about taking the Skill Focus feat in addition to Aereni Focus, only that Aereni Focus "counts" for specific purposes.

So, how does this resolve? Do I take it exactly as written, and since the limitation on Skill Focus being taken only once per skill is a special condition of the feat, Aereni Focus doesn't "count as" for that condition, allowing me to take both for a combined bonus of +6 on the skill? Or should Aereni Focus counting as Skill Focus for prerequisites and requirements include the "requirement" of having not taken Skill Focus in the same skill before, even though it's not written as such?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour], it's a useful introduction to the site. It is important that the Stack gets questions tagged appropriately so that experts can find it to answer, and so that others with the same question can get use from it. It's also important that we each do our best to [be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) on the Stack even when others aren't.

Answer (score 9):

Taking Aereni Focus does not prohibit you from taking Skill Focus in the same skill, they're two separate feats. In addition, the bonus for both feats aren't typed so they stack.

The rules in this case are very specific:

> Aereni Focus counts as Skill Focus for the purpose of meeting any requirement or prerequisite.

The Special section of Skill Focus which details skill focus's limit isn't a requirement or prerequisite. Aereni Focus doesn't count for the purpose of taking Skill Focus multiple times, only for requirements or prerequisites that list Skill Focus.